# Angular Material Components not rendering correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Angular Material components are not rendering properly. They should look like this:

[image]

Instead they render like this:

[image]

It was working fine until I started using Material and Reactive Forms.
I've tried everything. I usually find that if something like this happens the it is a problem with the Module. Code for the Module:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RegisterRoutingModule } from './register-routing.module';
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register.component";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { MatButtonModule, MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RegisterRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
      ],
      declarations: [RegisterComponent]
    })
export class RegisterModule { }
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Pretty weird that placeholders stop showing after last name's.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `matInput` from the input control solved the problem.

Previous code not rendering properly:

```
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="register(registerForm)">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" autofocus>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

Successfully rendering code:

```
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="register(registerForm)">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" autofocus>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

Comment: I ran into this as well and filed it as a bug on Angular's github. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37187

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any errors going out to console. I also saw this behavior - turns out Angular just has a strange response. You can see the air in [this stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-form-ngfor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

That code will issue `Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`

If you [fix the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-form-ngfor-fob4mi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the error will clear.

See [this github post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37187)